# How to install vue-chartkick and use it in my components?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, chart.js

I am using `vue-chartkick` with Laravel. I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick#quick-start) to install it.

```
npm install vue-chartkick chart.js
```

Then, in `resources/js/app.js`:

```
import Chartkick from 'vue-chartkick'
import Chart from 'chart.js'

Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chart))

...

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    vuetify: new Vuetify()
});
```

Then, when I put `<line-chart :data="{'2017-01-01': 11, '2017-01-02': 6}"></line-chart>` into a component, I get the following error in javascript console:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <line-chart> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Dashboard> at resources/js/components/backend/Dashboard.vue
       <VApp>
         <Root>
```

What is the correct way to register the component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use chart.js version 2.9 and vue-chartkick 0.6.1

```
npm install vue-chartkick@0.6.1 chart.js@2.9 --save
```

and import in app.js like below:

```
import {Chart} from 'chart.js'
import Chartkick from 'vue-chartkick'
Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chart));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Chartkick with Fastapi. I struggled to implement it on the backend (no npm installer), then found the solution at https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick#installation

Put the code inside your main template file eg index.html:

[image]

My main.js file, running on fastapi server:

```
import { MyTitle } from "./title.js";
import { MyName } from "./name.js";

export const app = Vue.createApp({
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
});

app.component("MyTitle", MyTitle);
app.component("MyName", MyName);
app.use(VueChartkick);

const vm = app.mount("#app");
```