# Vue chartkick not showing

Tags: vue.js, chartkick

I'm trying to use vue chartkick on my project. But when I run my project, it gives me two warnings

```
 WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings                                                                        08:41:24
 warning  in ./src/main.js

"export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js'

 warning  in ./node_modules/vue-chartkick/dist/vue-chartkick.esm.js

"export 'h' was not found in 'vue'
```

Here's what the console said

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown adapter
    at getAdapterType (chartkick.js?50d1:2036)
    at addAdapter (chartkick.js?50d1:2040)
    at Object.use (chartkick.js?50d1:2485)
    at eval (main.js?56d7:10)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1112)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1173)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
```

and my project became a blank white screen. How to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install the older version of chartkick and chartjs (because I'm using Vue 2) to make it work. Answer reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719470/how-to-install-vue-chartkick-and-use-it-in-my-components).